# Reveal PHP through a HTTPRequest

Tags: php, httprequest

I have a postage calculator algorithm written in PHP. One of our associate companies wanted to use it so found out the code via a HTTPRequest to our server.

How is it possible to see the PHP code this way?

I know some PHP code etc but I am a little stumped how they would access the code.
When I asked them about how they had access to my algorithm, their response was:

"We are sending HTTP request to your server similar to the request sent by your web pages."

Yet when I send a HTTPRequest I simply get JavaScript and HTML etc - not my PHP.

Sorry about the site - I didn't design it - very old thing - I just patch back end stuff.

Here is link to a page

http://www.directbuy.com.au/product_info.php?products_id=1042

If someone can let me know if they can find my Postage Calc then let me know how you if you did?

Comment: In general, it isn't. Either they're lying to you about stealing the code, or there is some bug in your code or server setup that leaked the data, but without any idea what your code does and how, we have no way of knowing what problems it might contain.

Comment: This sounds very unlikely unless the server was severely misconfigured. To be honest, I am reading this question as "someone else has a postage calculator algorithm, how can I steal the code using an HTTP request to their server?"

Comment: Sounds like they're just sending data to your server and getting their answer back, not your code. They're just using your site to do their math for them

Answer (score 0):

Via HTTP request and response, they would only see the input and output but not the PHP code since PHP is interpreted server-side.

This means that they could have potentially reverse-engineered the algorithm. For instance, if I sent a service 2 and received 4 then sent 4 and received 16 and so on, I might be able to reverse engineer the maths behind that (in this example the square function).

If they managed to access your server without going through a PHP server, then they would also be able to download the PHP source file. For instance, a PHP file on an Apache Tomcat server (a Java server) would be served as plain text and would therefore reveal the code.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like they're probably just sending a request using information from this form:

```
<form id="postage_form" action="product_info.php?&products_id=1042" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="sub_postcode" name="postcode" value="" />
</form>
```

and then scraping the result for the value of this input:

```
<input id="v_result" size="10" value="" type="text">
```

Probably with something like this:

```
<?php
$postcode = "2060";
$url = "http://www.directbuy.com.au/product_info.php?products_id=1042";
$name = "postcode";
$result_id = "v_result";
$post_values = array($name => $postcode);

$page = url_get_contents($url,$url,$post_values);
$dom = new DomDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($page);
$xp = new DOMXpath($dom);
$nodes = $xp->query("//input[@id='$result_id']");
$result = $nodes->item(0)->getAttribute('value');

var_dump($result);
```

Returns `string(5) "$40.7"`

Note: `url_get_contents` is a custom function that uses cURL